# Selenium Server - while running, keeps popping up firefox windows. Is there a way to force windows to be minimized?

Tags: firefox, selenium

when running a large test suite locally, Selenium at every test pops up with a window. If I'm doing other work, or just using the computer, this becomes very frustrating (especially for a test that's <1-2 minutes, because it runs for 40 locales, so every minute I get a popup.

Is there a way I can force firefox to start minimized? Or to have Selenium work on another screen/workspace so it does not interfere with what I am doing?

Comment: This is a common question, and can be googled easily.

Comment: I always google before asking here. My terminology always ends up with it talking about java script popups instead of what I want.

Comment: ok but I can only tell you what you already found out for yourself: Selenium does not do 3rd party flash apps

Answer (score 1):

You want to setup headless mode. It'll keep all the visual/browser stuff out of the way, and keep it in memory instead of pushing it to the graphics buffer.